# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input - Passport-local

Tags: node.js, json, ajax, passport-local

I am using passport local and I already got the user data using `req.session.passport.user`
But for some reason I am having trouble receiving the user data by using Ajax or fetch request.
Any ideas?

```
app.get('/api/student/compose', function(req, res) { 
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.json({
            data: req.session.passport.user
        });
      } else {
        res.json({data: "Not logged in!"});
      }
});
```

The following code is on the client side:

```
/**
 *  Get the user data
 *   
 *  @returns {Object} Return the user data
 */
async userData() {

    let url = `http://localhost:3000/api/student/compose`;
    let receivingData = {};

    await fetch(url, {
        method: "get",
        mode: "cors",

        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json", // expected data sent back
        }
    }).then((data) => {
            receivingData.data = data;
            receivingData.err = false;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            receivingData.err = true;
            receivingData.errMessage = error;
        });

    return receivingData;
}
```

Comment: Client side: Shouldn't you parse json data before referencing?
`await fetch(url, .....).then(res=>res.json()).then(data => ....)`

Comment: I tried that and i got an error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: so this is the error:

message: "Unexpected end of JSON input"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input↵    at http://127.0.0.1:3000/general/js/class/Auth.js:28:30↵    at async Auth.userData

Comment: I would recommend trying `fetch(url, .....).then(res=>res.text()).then(data => JSON.parse(data))`. I would also recommend against mixing await and `.then`. In your case you can remove the await and it would the same.